# How do I access base class variables through an instance of a child class in Python?

Tags: python, inheritance

I wanted to know how to access to the super class’s variables with a object of child class
If it makes any sense I add that some of the variables are defined  in this __variable name way. Any time I want to access the variables with a child object. Python says the object  with the type CHILE CLASS TYPE here is not defined. I wanted to know how I can solve this?
I also want to add that the super class is not explicitly defined and it is just imported from a module.

```
class AcuExcelSheet (  Worksheet  ):  ## super class which is imported from module 
    def __init__(self):
        Worksheet.__init__(self)

sheet = AcuExcelSheet()
for row_index in range(sheet.nrows):
        for col_index in range(sheet.ncols):
            print sheet.cell(row_index,col_index).value
```

for row_index in range(sheet.nrows):
AttributeError: 'AcuExcelSheet' object has no attribute 'nrows'

I want to know about the syntax of this class variable’s call. Because I can see that attribute nrow has been defined in the constructor of Worksheet class.

Comment: Maybe you can use dir() on an instance of Worksheet to see its attributes?

Comment: Please post a simple example showing what you don't understand.  As a bonus, I bet the act of making the simple example will tell you what's wrong.  Your current example is too incomplete to be able to tell you anything useful about it.  This is a poor question because of that.

Answer (score 4):

Something is wrong, but not with the code you've shown.  If `Worksheet` truly defines `.nrows`, then your `AcuExcelSheet` will have access to it.  There are a few possibilities:

1. `Worksheet` doesn't define nrows.  You mention double-underscore names.  Are you sure it isn't `__nrows`?
2. `Worksheet` defines nrows, but only for some code paths, and your invocation of the constructor doesn't hit those code paths.

Comment: The double-underscore prefix will mangle the name by adding the class name to it, e.g. `__nrows` in `AcuExcelSheet` would become `_AcuExcelSheet__nrows`  http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables

Answer (score 2):

Forgive me if I'm misunderstanding something, but doesn't the child class automatically inherit the methods of the super class? See this for example:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...             self.data = "GIMME TEH DATA"
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a.data
'GIMME TEH DATA'
>>> class B(A):
...     pass
... 
>>> b = B()
>>> b.data
'GIMME TEH DATA'
```

So the superclass A's **init** method sets the `data` attribute. B is the child class, and an instance of B has automatically the same `data` attribute initialised.

What I mean to say from this is that this part seems entirely unnecessary to me:

```
def __init__(self):
    Worksheet.__init__(self)
```

(As for the rest I agree with the commenter that you'd need to either use introspection or find documentation to find out what attributes `Worksheet` has -- something along the lines of

```
>>> a = Worksheet()
>>> print dir(a)
```

.)

Answer (score 0):

There's no separated base class instance dictionary in object instances. As line

```
Worksheet.__init__(self)
```

says objects of AcuExcelSheet are initialized by Worksheet class. All may you need - to access base class method, that was redefined, you can do it just by

```
super(AcuExcelSheet,self).method_name
```

expression. So if you can't find some attributes in child class instance, maybe it needs some additional initialization.